Why is my React embed widget not displaying?
I have two carousels which can be seen here: https://blueprint-courses.netlify.app
I have then compiled my react code
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "postbuild": "mkdir -p public && cp build/static/js/main*.js public/widget-loader.js",
    "build-widget": "npm run build && npm run postbuild"
  },  

And deployed it here: https://blueprint-courses.netlify.app/widget-loader.js
I have then went to Kajabi CMS and added the below to the custom code component like this:
<div id="my-carousel-widget-1"></div>

<script src="https://blueprint-courses.netlify.app/widget-loader.js"></script>

but my carousel is not displaying.
I have previously got it working not using react. For example see this web page: https://blueprintcourses.netlify.app/my-carousel-widget-3/
which I managed to display onto my Kajabi site using:
<div id="my-carousel-widget-3"></div>

<script src="https://blueprintcourses.netlify.app/my-carousel-widget-3/widget-loader.js"></script>


I ideally want to use React hence why I am trying to do it with the first example. I am more comfortable with react and it's easier to read.
